# What is the source/inspiration behind the Tusken Raiders' grunting language, out-of-universe?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In Season 2 of *The Mandalorian*, we are given a closer understanding about the infamous **Sand people** where they are shown to be a species out to be a proper culture and rooted in tradition. In **Chapter 9: The Marshal** when Din Djarin is helping the natives of Mos Pelgo alongside the Tuskens, we see two things:

- The Tuskens do have some sort of sign language that they use. Its out-of-universe source/inspiration is answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224055/is-the-mandalorian-using-out-of-universe-real-sign-language) and also explained [here](https://www.syfy.com/syfywire/the-mandalorian-tusken-raider-sign-language)
- They also use some sort of grunts (*sounded to me more like grunting angry pigs*) to attract the Kryat Dragon

Out-of-universe, what is the source/inspiration behind these grunting sounds used by the Tuskens?

Answer (score 4):

The calls used by the Tusken Raiders in the episode [when drawing out the Krayt Dragon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AzvGS192Ks) sound like reuses or recreations of the [Tusken calls from the original film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOoestw0Qng).

This is supported by an interview on the [Tonebenders Podcast](https://tonebenderspodcast.com/) with the Mandalorian Season Two sound team in which the sound designers say that their philosophy with the show was to reuse archival sounds for creatures or technology that had an established sound from the films. According to Sound Designer and Supervising Sound Editor Dave Acord:

> Jon Favreau, or Dave Filoni, or the picture editors, the episodic directors all have their own idea of what this should sound like. And if it's a brand new thing, you know, then obviously we're rolling with that, bring whatever's in their head into reality. And that's the goal, right? But for certain things like X-wings, or stormtrooper guns, or certain things that have history, you know, R2-D2, that have an established sound, you're really not going to mess with that too much, and everybody knows that. I haven't really encountered a filmmaker on these shows that wants to sort of reinvent the wheel, in a way. People have a sort of global respect for the legacy sounds of the show. Because I think that that's kind of a part of the history of the franchise itself, are those sound effects. So you don't want to record new Chewbacca, or something. [...] There are some things like the stormtrooper guns, in Mandalorian, that have that sort of original Ben Burtt stormtrooper sound, that we've given it a little beef, a little extra zip to it, a little whatever, but it's always rooted in that sound.
>
> <sub>[Tonebenders 153: The Mandalorian with Bonnie Wild & Dave Acord](https://tonebenderspodcast.com/153-the-mandalorian-with-bonnie-wild-dave-acord/)</sub>

Based on [an excerpt of an interview](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/La5-cH_Gav4) with sound designer [Ben Burtt](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ben_Burtt), the original sounds used for the Tuskens were based on the mules used by the filming crew in Tunisia during production:

> The mules which were used to backpack the camera gear into the location in Tunisia. I think it was Gary Kurtz or George Lucas that heard **the braying of these mules** and had the sound man go out and record them in the rocks, and they sent them back to me. They didn't really know what they were going to be used for, but it seemed to me that they were Tusken Raiders. And so **the basis for the Tusken Raiders were really mules**, which were cut up a bit and changed in speed, and then eventually I did some more animals back here in the United States. I even recorded a person who could imitate a mule, and by taking those various recordings we were able to come up with several different Tusken Raider voices.
>
> <sub>Ben Burtt interview via ["Tusken Raider Sounds Come From..." on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/La5-cH_Gav4); emphasis added</sub>